# Recursively Build a String from an Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array that places values on specific indices, like so:

```
{4: 6, 8: 1}
```

It can sometimes have arrays inside it. I have a function that builds a string from scratch, due to the fact that converting the array to a string places all the indices with no values in that string, and sometimes indices can be in the multi-millions.

Note that GetValue is a separate function and returns an object, and DatabaseArray is just a special type of array Player.IO uses. I'll also point out that I don't simply use a foreach because I need to display the index.

```
value = "{";
DatabaseArray copiedarray = (DatabaseArray)result.GetValue(i);
for (int j = 0; j < copiedarray.Count; j++)
{
    if (copiedarray.Contains(j))
    {
        if (value != "{")
        {
            value = value + ", ";
        }
        value = value + j + ": " + copiedarray.GetValue(j).ToString();
    }
}
value = value + "}";
```

This works on the top level, but not any underlying arrays. It will turn this:

```
{0: <null>, 1: <null>, 2: <null>, 3: {0: <null>, 1: 2}, 4: 5}
```

Into this:

```
{3: {0: <null>, 1: 2}, 4: 5}
```

But I want to make it this:

```
{3: {1: 2}, 4: 5}
```

I can't find a way to make it reiterate through and build all the underlying arrays. I should note that there is an unknown number of nested arrays, and that I cannot simply convert to a string and remove the null lines because I get OutOfMemoryExceptions on really large indices.

Comment: do you want to form a json string?

Comment: How do you mean? I just need a string that contains all the indices with non-null values.

Comment: An array is a fixed-size collection of objects of a particular type T. I  fail to see how the array can contain objects of type T as well as a 'nested array (presumably of type T). Please explain.

Comment: As I noted, it's a special array. It's not bound to a single type, it can have ints and arrays or strings and arrays, and probably all 3 and more. I don't know too much on it since it is a PlayerIO specific type, but that much I know.

Comment: @Cool12309 why do you want to keep `0: <null>,` in the inner array.

Comment: I do not, that is why I need help building the arrays. Basically, for each value, if it's anything but an array it can just be turned into a string. If it's an array, it needs to be built manually into a string and then returned. If it has another array inside it, that needs to be built first, and if that has one, that, etc.

Comment: @Cool12309 you remove null values from the first level array but not from the inner one. what is the rule?

Comment: All of them must be removed. I put that there because that's what it does currently, it does not remove it.

Comment: when you say `It will turn this: ...` into this `....` What I understand is you want the second part. But now you say `what it does currently` I don't understand what you say. Anyway, voting to close as `unclear what is asked`,

Comment: There, I edited the question. I don't know what you're confused about: The first part is what doing a .ToString() on it does, the second part is what it's doing currently, and the third part (which I just added) is what I want it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I assume that DatabaseArray.GetValue() can return another DatabaseArray you could create a recursive method something like this:

```
        private string GetArrayString(object dbArray)
        {
            if (dbArray == null) return null;

            var arrayString = "{";
            var copiedarray = (DatabaseArray)dbArray;
            for (var i = 0; i < copiedarray.Count; i++)
            {
                if (copiedarray.Contains(i))
                {
                    if (arrayString != "{")
                    {
                        arrayString = arrayString + ", ";
                    }
                    var value = copiedarray.GetValue(i);
                    arrayString = arrayString + i + ": " + (value is DatabaseArray ? this.GetArrayString(value) : value);
                }
            }
            arrayString += "}";
            return arrayString;
        }
```

Then call it like this:

```
DatabaseArray copiedarray = (DatabaseArray)result.GetValue(i);
return GetArrayString(copiedarray);
```

That should output this:

```
{3: {1: 2}, 4: 5}
```

Comment: Beautiful! The simplest solutions turn out to be the best!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, but I'm not entirely sure if I understood the format your array is in though.  This method assumes each item in the object[] array is either a string, or another array (which is then in turn composed of either strings or arrays etc).

```
    private static void ToFormattedString(this object[] array)
    {
        var res = array.Select((item, index) => 
                            new { Index = index, Item = item is IEnumerable<object>
                                          ? (item as object[]).ToFormattedString()
                                          : item })
                       .Where(i => i.Item != null);

        return "{" + string.Join(", ", res.Select(r => r.Index.ToString() + ": " + r.Item.ToString())) + "}";
    }
```

Usage:

```
object[] array = //Get the array

string arrayString = array.ToFormattedString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for recursion!  I'm not exactly sure what the use case for this is, but on a very basic level, because you're recursively writing each array out, you should write...well...a recursive method.

```
   public string GetArrayString()
        {
            var arrayValues = new object[]{
                1,2,3,new[]{4,5,6}
            };

            return this.FormatArrayValues(arrayValues);
        }

        public string FormatArrayValues(IEnumerable<object> arrayValues)
        {
            String s = "{";

            arrayValues = arrayValues.Where(w=>w != null).ToArray();

            for(int j = 0; j < arrayValues.Count();j++){

                var currentValue = arrayValues.ElementAt(j);

                if(currentValue is int[])
                {
                    var currentValueAsArrayOfObj = ((int[])currentValue).Cast<object>();
                    currentValue = this.FormatArrayValues(currentValueAsArrayOfObj);
                }

                s += String.Format("{0}:{1}{2}",j, currentValue, j + 1 != arrayValues.Count() ? "," : null);

            }

            s += "}";

            return s;
        }
```

As a side note, why would you need the clause `if (copiedarray.Contains(j)){}` if you are iterating through the array...shouldn't it always contain 'j'.

Also, 'foreach' is sometimes a cleaner loop, and you can retrieve the index by using Linq's '`ElementAt()`' method.  In this case the `for-loop` is probably better, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the arrayValues line: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). Also, no, it won't, because the values are placed at specific indices (as in, index 5 could have a value but indice 2 won't)

Answer (score 0):

Since `System.Array` is special, one can't directly inherit from from it: your `DatabaseArray` has to be something other than an array. So, assuming that your `DatabaseArray` is some array-like object that implements the non-generic `System.Collections.IList` (something that all arrays and array-like objects do...or are supposed to do :D)...

You can look at nested arrays as being a form of tree.

Walking such a tree is a simple recursive algorithm. The following should do you. You'll need to provide it with:

- the root node your tree (the initial `IList`).
- A `StringBuilder` instance in which to build out the string
- An Action -- a delegate method or closure responsible stringifying non-null data objects. This `visitNode` delegate has to have the signature

  ```
  void visitNode( int i , object o , StringBuilder sb ) ;
  ```

All this `Action` has to do is append the string representation of the `object` and its `int` index to the `StringBuilder`. The simplest formatter would be something as simple as:

```
visitNode( int i , object o , StringBuilder sb )
{
  sb.AppendFormat( "{0} : {1}" , i , o ) ;
}
```

Once the `TreeWalk` completes, the `StringBuilder` should have the formatted string. Just invoke its `ToString()` method and bob's yer uncle.

```
static void TreeWalk( IList list , StringBuilder buffer , Action<int,object,StringBuilder> visitNode , int? index )
{
  // Enforce the contract's preconditions
  if ( list      == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "list"      ) ;
  if ( buffer    == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "buffer"    ) ;
  if ( visitNode == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "visitNode" ) ;

  // write the lead-in curly brace, prefixed with the optional index
  if ( index.HasValue )
  {
    buffer.Append( index.Value ).Append( " : ") ;
  }
  buffer.Append( "{"  ) ;

  // visit each direct child
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.Count ; ++i )
  {
    // write the item separator
    if ( i > 0 )
    {
      buffer.Append( " , " ) ;
    }

    // get the current child
    object child = list[i] ;


    if ( child == null )
    {
      // if the child is null, we skip it
      continue ;
    }
    else if ( child is IList )
    {
      // if the child is a [nested] IList, we recursively visit it
      TreeWalk( (IList)child , buffer , visitNode ) ;
    }
    else
    {
      // if the child is anything else, it's data: just visit it
      visitNode( i , child , buffer ) ;
    }

  }

  // write the lead-out curly brace
  buffer.Append( " }" ) ;

  return ;
}
```

Comment: All those ILists are giving me an error: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>' requires 1 type arguments. Also, this is way too advanced for me, you're going to have to dumb it down.

Comment: That's because you need to reference `System.Collections`.

This is not a generic interface. And this is about as simple as it gets. It's pretty trivial to convert from recursion to explicitly using a stack, but it doesn't really make it any simpler.

And if you'd rather not deal with the `Action` delegate `visitNode`, just strip it out of the prototype and replace the line that calls `visitNode` to `buffer.AppendFormat( "{0} : {1}" , i , child ) ;`